# Delete relational join tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-delete

The following are the tables are an example of the issue I am having:

**Companies** *{Id}*

**CompanyPeople** *{CompanyId, PeopleId}*

**People** *{Id}*

**PeopleChildren** *{PeopleId, ChildrenId}*

**Children** *{Id}*

I want to delete all the people of a company and then delete the children of the people.

I cannot delete the people without deleting the items in the join table **CompanyPeople**. However if I do this I cannot find which people are part of the company.

The same issue follows down to **Children**

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally use [table variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx) or [temp tables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) to capture the data to be used first, and then perform the deletes:

```
declare @people table (PersonID int not null)
create table #children (ChildrenID int not null)

insert into @people(PersonID)
select PersonID from CompanyPeople
where CompanyID = @CompanyToRemove
insert into #children (ChildrenID)
select ChildrenID from PeopleChildren
where PersonID in (select PersonID from @people)

delete from PeopleChildren where PersonID in (select PersonID from @people)
delete from Children where ChildrenID in (select ChildrenID from #children)
delete from CompanyPeople where PersonID in (select PersonID from @people)
delete from People where PersonID in (select PersonID from @people)
```

Comment: If this was in a stored procedure would the @people or #children tables be remembered, I ask because if it is run a second time will the people deleted previously tried to be deleted again

Comment: @user2021962 - both table variables and temp tables, if created inside a stored procedure have lifetimes that last until the end of the stored procedure, and are then cleaned up. (And by the way, I've only used both to show the syntax, for real life, I'd probably just stick with the table variable style for both `@people` and `@children`)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the children of the people who are in the company you want to delete first by

```
delete from Children where ChildrenID in (select ChildrenID from Children, PeopleChildren, CompanyPeople where Children.ChildrenID = PeopleChildren.ChildrenID and PeopleChildren.PeopleID = CompanyPeople.PeopleID and CompanyPeople.CompanyID = ?)
```

Then only you delete the people by

```
delete from People where PeopleID in (select PeopleID from CompanyPeople where CompanyPeople.CompanyID = ?)
```

Comment: Yay. Pre-ANSI joins. Joins have only been in the standard for 20+ years and adopted by every SQL vendor I can think of. Also, the OP's issue is that they can't delete from e.g. `Children` without first deleting the rows from `PeopleChildren` that presumably have an enforced foreign key constraint to `Children`.

Comment: OP can change the foreign key constraint to ON DELETE CASCADE. When he deletes a record from Children. The records in PeopleChildren which refer to the deleted Children will be deleted as well.

Answer (score 0):

i think i will use output clause,i think this will be fast because of no insert and few less sql statement

this is not complete

```
declare @people table (PersonID int not null)
 DELETE FROM PeopleChildren
FROM  @people p INNER JOIN
 PeopleChildren pc  ON p.ID = pc.ID
 output deleted.id into @people

 delete from People p 
 from People inner join  @people p1 on p.PersonID=p1. PersonID
```

Comment: the `output` clause comes before the (second) `FROM`. See [`DELETE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever,there may be syntax error,i just gave idea